# How best to show the removal of a variable in workings so others can follow?

Tags: integration, random-variables

My text book has the following question:
Approximate the probability that the sum of 16 independent uniform (0,1) random variables exceeds 10.

Let $X_i$ be $i^{th}$ independently uniformly distributed random variable.

$$E[X_i]=\int_0^1 p(x)x dx = \int_0^1 \left[\frac{x^2}{2} \right]_0^1 $$
$$Var[X_i] = \int_0^1 p(x)(x-E[X_i])^2 dx$$
$$=\int_0^1(x-0.5)^2 dx$$
$$=\left[\frac{(x-0.5)^3}{3}\right]_0^1 $$
$$=\frac{1}{12}$$

Why is the p(x) dropped between the second and third line?

I am thinking that perhaps it is because it evaluates to 1.
But I feel that could have been noted better.

Very complete answers help me to learn.
How would that step best be documented?

Would a note like "since p(x)=1" suffice.

Is this in fact the reason?

Comment: The PDF of a $U(0,1)$ random variable is $p=1_{[0,1]}$, the indicator of the interval $[0,1]$. So $p(x)=1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. I don't know what better explanation you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, the probability density of such a uniform random variable is constant on $(0,1)$ and such that $\int p(x)\,\mathrm dx$ over said interval is $1$. -- Also, I would suspect that you have calculated tha variance of such a uniform varuable somewhere in the past before this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf of $U(0,1)$ is indeed $1$ over $[0,1]$. This explains why $p(x)$ is simply "deleted" from line 2 to line 3.

If it is written that $p(x)=1$ earlier in the presentation, that would suffice to explain the step.